# How do I sort JavaScript strings by codePoint?

Tags: javascript, sorting, unicode

I am looking to sort objects by a string field that contains unicode characters. However, I want to sort the strings by code point, not by locale. So, here is an example, where JavaScript sorts objects so that `\u24B7` and `b` are both considered the same character.

Incorrect sort order:

```
> [{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}, {name: 'd'}, {name: '\u24B7'}].sort((a,b)=> a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
[ { name: 'a' }, { name: 'b' }, { name: 'Ⓑ' }, { name: 'd' } ]
```

However, this is *not* what I want. I want the following sort order, where they are considered different characters. This is the default behavior when comparing strings and not including a comparator function.

Correct sorting order (notice that `b` and `\u24B7` are no longer considered the same sort character):

```
> ['a','b','\u24B7','d'].sort()
[ 'a', 'b', 'd', 'Ⓑ' ]
```

In the real application, the strings will be more than one character and may contain multiple unicode chars and we want them sorted according to unicode number (ie- code point).

My question: is there a simple way to sort by code point for strings? I'd rather not re-implement a custom comparator for this.

Comment: Do you insist on comparing code points, or would comparing UTF16 code units be enough?

Comment: No, doesn't need to be code points, the important thing is that unicode characters need to be distinct from their locale-specific synonyms (I don't know the correct terminology here).

Comment: Yeah, then the standard string comparison will do for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually do it like this:

```
let cmp = (a, b) => a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;

objects.sort((a, b) => cmp(a.name, b.name));
```

or rather

```
let sortBy = (a, f) => a.sort((x, y) => cmp(f(x), f(y)));

sortBy(objects, x => x.name);
```

Comment: You usually use nested ternary operations? Shame on you

Comment: Forgiving the lack of explanation, this isn't code golf. Readability is huge in code, and ternary operators, let alone nested, are awful to read. (Not my downvote, btw)

Comment: nested ternaries make people stabby. watch out.

Comment: I think nested ternaries are fine as long as you use proper parens to clearly demarcate grouping (which I would ask for if I were code reviewing this), but as an answer, I think it is fine. I'm just trying it out now.

Comment: @SterlingArcher I see nothing wrong with this. Ternary operators are much more useful, and easier to read, than `if` statements - at least with a functional mindset. That single-line `cmp` function can be determined with a quick glance to compare the two argument values and return `1`/`0`/`-1` as appropriate for a sort comparison function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works for me. I didn't realize that < and > on strings compares them using code points.

Comment: JavaScript comparison operators on strings do *not* compare using code points! They compare using UTF-16 code units. This means any string with codepoints outside of the Basic Multilingual Plane will sort incorrectly, especially if the string also contains BMP codepoints from U+E000 and above. `"\uFE0F" < "\u{1F926}"` evaluates to `false`!